# How to make app run from specific path only?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

How to make the program not work through DVD and work only through the HDD?
With a condition if it's in a different drive other than `C:` then it does not work.

**My code attempt**:

```
stop();
import flash.filesystem.*;

var file: File = File.documentsDirectory;
var file2: File = File.documentsDirectory;

if (file.nativePath.indexOf("C:\Town\9.swf") != 0) 
{
    while (true) stage.removeChildAt(0);
    gotoAndPlay(15);

} 
else if (file2.nativePath.indexOf("D:\Town\9.swf") != 0)
{
    while (true) stage.removeChildAt(0); 
    
    fscommand("quit");

}
```

Comment: Extremely crude, but will do what you asked for. Add this one line: **if (file.nativePath.indexOf("C:/") != 0) while (true) stage.removeChildAt(0);**

Comment: stop();
import flash.filesystem.*;

var file: File = File.documentsDirectory;
var file2: File = File.documentsDirectory;

if (file.nativePath.indexOf("C:\Town\9.swf") != 0) {
 while (true) stage.removeChildAt(0);

 gotoAndPlay(15)

} else if (file2.nativePath.indexOf("D:\Town\9.swf") != 0){
 while (true) stage.removeChildAt(0); 

 fscommand("quit");


}

Comment: I see the edits. What is the point of doing **while (true) ...** in either case?

Comment: I want to specify to run the file from C:

Comment: If you want to change the code, don't mind

Comment: Thank you for caring
I am working on an educational project that I need to work through the hard disk only and not work through the DVD
I need to make a condition, if it is available, it works through the hard disk, which is a file path from within the project, and if the project is inside the DVD, it does not work
Thank you

Comment: I need my application to work only from specific path (i.e. c:\user\  ,or c:\myapp)

Comment: stop();
import flash.filesystem.*;

var file: File = File.documentsDirectory;

if (file.nativePath.indexOf("c:\karam\9.swf")); = (file.nativePath.indexOf("c:\karam\9.swf"));
 {

  gotoAndPlay(15)

 }

Comment: @karamElFekey Is your problem solved now? The first comment (by Organis) tells you a possible solution, which is to check if the path of your app location has `C:/` in the result (or you can also try as `C:\ ` if check is still not working).